# GetElementsByClass for all href link tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently i am trying with Javascript to change the font color from a `<a>` tag it needs to happen when you scroll down the color changes from white to black but i have been struggling that when you scroll down it only changes one `<a>` tag to black and the rest stays white.

This is a short code how my nav is like:

```
    <div class="rc_nav" id="centered_nav">
        <a href="#home" class="link1">Home</a>
        <a href="#services" class="link1">Services</a>
        <a href="#about" class="link1">About</a>
        <a href="#contact" class="link1">Contact</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Menu" style="font-size:18px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
```

And this is how my javascript looks like

```
const nav = document.getElementById('centered_nav');
const logo = document.getElementById('rc_logo');
const link = document.getElementsByClassName('link1')[0];

window.onscroll = function(){

    if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {

        nav.style.background = "#FFFFFF";
        nav.style.boxShadow = "0px 2px 1px #E55200";
        link.style.color = "#000000";
        logo.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://localhost/assets/img/nav-logo-color.png')";
    }
    else {
        nav.style.background = "transparent";
        nav.style.boxShadow = "none";
        link.style.color = "#FFFFFF";
        logo.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://localhost/assets/img/nav-logo.png')";
    }
}
```

I have done some research because i am not that familiar with Javascript but without any results. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: I updated my answer to include a better css-based format, along with transition animation for a more flowing UX

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer is that you're affecting many links, not one, so you need to create a collection and iterate through it with something like `forEach`. In your code you were using `document.getElementsByClassName('link1')[0];` which is just the FIRST link.

```
const nav = document.getElementById('centered_nav');
const logo = document.getElementById('rc_logo');
const links = document.getElementsByClassName('link1');

window.onscroll = function(){
    if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {
        nav.style.background = "#FFFFFF";
        nav.style.boxShadow = "0px 2px 1px #E55200";
        links.forEach(link => link.style.color = "#000000" );
        logo.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://localhost/assets/img/nav-logo-color.png')";
    }
    else {
        nav.style.background = "transparent";
        nav.style.boxShadow = "none";
        links.forEach(link => link.style.color = "#ffffff" );
        logo.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://localhost/assets/img/nav-logo.png')";
    }
}
```

The better answer is to just set a single class on `body` perhaps, and then have your css rules do the rest. You can even add transitions this way which will allow you to animate the transition from white to black etc. I put the transition rules in here, you can remove if desired.

```
const body = document.querySelector('body');
window.onscroll = function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > 100) body.classList.add('scrolled')
  else body.classList.remove('scrolled')
}
```

The css:

```
#rc_logo {
  background-image: url('http://localhost/assets/img/nav-logo.png');
}
#centered_nav {
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition: background .5s linear .5s;
}
.link1 {
  color: #fff;
  transition: background .5s linear .5s;
}

body.scrolled #rc_logo {
  background-image: url('http://localhost/assets/img/nav-logo-color.png');
}
body.scrolled #centered_nav {
  background: #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px #E55200;
  transition: background .5s linear .5s;
}
body.scrolled .link1 {
  color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all the anchor elements and loop over them to set the color. (Note that `document.querySelectorAll` is preferred over `document.getElementsByClassName` because the returned collection is not live.)

```
const nav = document.getElementById('centered_nav');
const logo = document.getElementById('rc_logo');
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.link1');

window.onscroll = function(){

    if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {

        nav.style.background = "#FFFFFF";
        nav.style.boxShadow = "0px 2px 1px #E55200";
        links.forEach(link => link.style.color = "#000000");
        logo.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://localhost/assets/img/nav-logo-color.png')";
    }
    else {
        nav.style.background = "transparent";
        nav.style.boxShadow = "none";
        links.forEach(link => link.style.color = "#FFFFFF");
        logo.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://localhost/assets/img/nav-logo.png')";
    }
}
```